# sort list of Controls from a custom class type

Tags: c#, list, class

I have a problem in order my list, I check most of the example but I think my problem is unique. Please check and help me to get it done.

```
List<Control> lc = new List<Control>();

foreach (Control control in fLP.Controls)
{
   Dashboard_Env_Details ded =  (Dashboard_Env_Details)control;
   ded.refreshUC();
   lc.Add(control);
}

List<Control> Sortedlc = lc.OrderBy((o => ((Dashboard_Env_Details)o).custTask.getNoInvalidObjects).ToList();
```

I am receiving below error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0411  The type arguments for method
>   'Enumerable.OrderBy(IEnumerable, Func)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type
>   arguments
>   explicitly.   KeepMyServerInfo    C:\Users\CM_Dashboard.cs    141 Active

Comment: What problem do you have?

Comment: Please specify the problem more thoroughly and also tell us what is `custTask` and `getNoInvalidObjects`

Comment: @MartinZikmund: consider those as two simple class.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have too many left parentheses. I would use `OfType` or `Cast` or store the controls in a `List<Dashboard_Env_Details>` instead:

```
List<Control> Sortedlc = lc.Cast<Dashboard_Env_Details>()
 .OrderBy(o => o.custTask.getNoInvalidObjects)
 .Select(o => (Control) o)
 .ToList();
```

If the list contains also other controls you could use `OfType`.

Comment: same error

:

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0411 The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. KeepMyServerInfo C:\\CM_Dashboard.cs 141 Active

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<KeepMyServerInfo.Dashboard_Env_Details>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Windows.Forms.Control>' KeepMyServerInfo

Comment: @Amir: have a look